# Ext JS 4.2.1 - renderTo causes error

Tags: javascript, templates, extjs, extjs4.2

I created a custom component with an XTemplate like this:

```
initComponent: function () {        
    this.initLayout();
    this.callParent();
},

initLayout: function() {
    var me = this;
    var mainTpl = this.getTemplate();
    Ext.apply(me, { html: mainTpl.apply() });
},
```

in my template i got some placeholders where i want to render some textfields...
so i tried to accomplish this in an eventhandler like that:

```
listeners: {       
    render: function () {
        var usrPlaceHolder = Ext.query('li.LoginUsername');
        if (usrPlaceHolder) {
            Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
                renderTo: usrPlaceHolder
            });
        }
    }
}
```

my Ext.query function does find the correct DOM Element, though the Ext.create with the renderTo config does throw the following Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createRange' of undefined
```

if you need any further information like a callstack or something.. dont hesitate to ask..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ext.query` returns an array, which is probably not what `renderTo` is expecting.

Use `Ext.dom.Query.selectNode` instead, or `Ext.query('li.LoginUsername')[0]`, or anything that will give you a single element.

Comment: oh my got - thought that it would be something silly which i'm not recognizing :D thx!